# Abstract algebra permutation and order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group. Define a relation $\sim$ on $G$ by $a\sim b$ if there exists $g\in G$ such that $a=gbg^{-1}$. Prove that all elements of order $15$ in $S_8$ are related by $\sim$.

I noticed that in order to have order 15 in S8, we need to have a product of 3 cycle and 5 cycle. Then, I am stuck... What should I do?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed in order to have order $15$ in $S_8$, we need to have a product of $3$-cycle and $5$-cycle. This means all the elements of order $15$ in $S_8$ have the same cyclic structure, and a theorem states that $2$ elements in $S_n$ are coniugate if and only if they have the same cyclic structure.